# Problems when viewing a DWG file translated to an SVF file with Autodesk Forge Viewer API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm trying to visualize a DWG file with the Forge Viewer.The translation into SVF format is all clear and smooth.
If it's not clear, graphically the SVF looks exactly the same as the DWG file when visualized with Autodesk Electrical, it's just that some of the "line" components are considered as fragmented into more and unrelated "line" components.

For example if I had one line in the DWG file, on the SVF visualized on the Viewer this line is fragmented into more lines that don't even have an attribute that relates them to each other.

I tried checking the metadata of the SVF file and there is no "parental" relation with this group of lines.

As a solution I was thinking to add an attribute to the lines in Autodesk Electrical, which would be the same for each "subline" that is part of a "line", though I was wondering if this could be a problem I could fix through the translation process in Forge.

Answer (score 0):

Is it actual straight line segments that are being split into multiple lines? Note that the SVF format can handle line segments, circular arcs, and elliptical arcs, but more general curves have to be tessellated into line segments.

As for attaching data to these drawing elements, you could potentially store the data separately from the SVF/F2D file, and link them to the drawing elements through their ACad handles or the SVF "dbIDs".